# Posicionar una tabla a la derecha

Tags: css, bootstrap

Quiero hacer que una tabla se ponga a lado de otra tabla, a la primera tabla no le agregué nada de estilo de posicionamiento, a la segunda intenté escribiendo:

```
<table class="table table-dark" style="position:absolute; top:23px; left:20px;" >
```

Pero no me funciona, incluso se empalma e intenté moviéndole los *px* y ahí ir calculando, pero de ahí no se puede sin importar, adjunto la imagen:

[image: t]

Comment: Estimado, por favor deja tu código como un ejemplo mínimo verificable para poder ayudarte con mas claridad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

una forma de hacerlo es manejando div y creando una fila con dos columnas:

```
<div class="row">
<div class = "col-sm-6">
<!--aqui va la primera tabla-->
</div>
<div class = "col-sm-6">
<!--aqui va la segunda tabla-->
</div>
</div>
```

o de esta otra forma:

```html
<div style="float:left;">
    <table>
      <tr><td>primera tabla</td></tr>
      <tr><td>primera tabla</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    <table>
      <tr><td>segunda tabla</td></tr>
      <tr><td>segunda tabla</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: No funciono, lo descuadro todavia mas

Comment: Entonces creo que tu problema debe ser divs que no estan cerrados, o alguna celda de la tabla que no cerraste. podrias poner tu codigo por favor.

Answer (score 3):

Prueba este **snippet** tienes que agregar un contenedor `row 2` y dentro otros dos de `6 md` cada uno si utilizas **`boostrap`**.

Para que puedas ver mejor el resultado te recomiendo que le des a la opción ver pagina completa o Ampliar.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-md-6">
  <table class="table table-sm table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <table class="table table-sm table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no agregas un estilo de posicionamiento, por defecto es relative. Si a una tabla le pones absolute y la posicionas, a la otra también debes ponérselo porque si no te ocurre eso, la posicionada con absolute se coloca sobre la otra a la distancia de píxeles que le especificas.

Otra solución es poner en las dos tablas position:relative; y float:left; de esta forma, se colocará una seguida de la otra.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Alinear tablas</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <table class="" style="position:relative; top:23px; left:20px; background-color:#459A1E; width:200px; height: 200px; float: left;"></table>
    <table class="" style="position:relative; top:23px; left:20px;  background-color:#AC1C1E; width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left;"></table>
</body>
</html>
```